# Postgres how can I get total sum 0 for null data between date, with month number

Tags: postgresql

I have a table called summary coins , where I am trying to get sumof coins group by month.I have written query

```
SELECT DATE_PART('month', date) AS MONTH,
    NULLIF(SUM(GET_COUNT),
        0) AS TOTAL
FROM SUMMARY_COINS
    AND date >= '2020-12-01'
    AND date <= '2021-05-01'
GROUP BY MONTH
ORDER BY MONTH ASC
```

I am getting the result like below

```
3   22
4   77
5   34
```

My desire output is

```
12     0
2      0
3      22
4      77
5      34
```

Here I am using NULLIF, but why not getting month total 0, where data is null for this month ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this will work

```sql
CREATE TABLE SUMMARY_COINS (
  date date primary key,
  GET_COUNT int
);

INSERT INTO SUMMARY_COINS VALUES
('2020-11-04', 4),
('2021-03-05', 4),
('2021-03-07', 1),
('2021-05-02', 2),
('2021-07-09', 3),
('2021-08-22', 5),
('2021-11-23', 6);

SELECT DATE_PART('year', x) AS year, DATE_PART('month', x) AS month, COALESCE(TOTAL, 0) AS total
 FROM generate_series(
    date_trunc('month', date'2020-10-01'),
    date_trunc('month', date'2021-11-01'),
    interval'1 month') AS x(x)
 LEFT JOIN LATERAL (
   SELECT SUM(GET_COUNT) AS TOTAL
     FROM SUMMARY_COINS
   WHERE date_trunc('month', date) = x
 ) AS s ON TRUE
ORDER BY x;
```

the output will give you totals for every month in the range specified in generate_series(..)

Answer (score 1):

`NULLIF()` doesn't look like what you want; it returns `NULL` if its parameters are equal. (You may have been thinking of `IFNULL()`, but this doesn't exist in Postgres.)

Instead, use `COALESCE(SUM(GET_COUNT), 0)`. `COALESCE()` returns its first non-NULL parameter.

[Source](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/functions-conditional.html)

Comment: I have tried by COALESCE but getting same result.

Answer (score 1):

Your table does not contain data for all the months and this is why your query is missing some months.

What you can do is create a resultset with all the months with a recursive CTE and then do a LEFT join to your table to aggregate:

```
WITH RECURSIVE months(month) AS (
  SELECT 1
  UNION ALL
  SELECT month + 1 FROM months WHERE month < 6
)  
SELECT m.month,
       COALESCE(SUM(GET_COUNT), 0) total
FROM months m LEFT JOIN SUMMARY_COINS s
ON DATE_PART('month', s.date) = m.month
AND s.date >= '2021-01-01' AND s.date <= '2021-06-01'
GROUP BY m.month
ORDER BY m.month;
```

See a simplified [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/yrZ9nU3jKb9yDtPumYp4F/0).

Comment: I am sorry after add WHERE USER_ID = 1, I am getting again old result ? Where I have to use where condition to get where user_id = 1 ?

Comment: @NiloyRony not in the WHERE clause. Add it in the ON clause.

Comment: I am getting here counting of month but not month number. Example my start date is 2021-12-01 then my exception is 12,1,2,3,4,5 . But I am getting 1,2,3,4,5,6.

Comment: @NiloyRony if your starting date and end date are in different years then you should have mentioned this in your question.

Comment: I am extremely sorry that I am failed to described this clearly. I have changed my example in question.